# What is a good multi language translation system for individual parts of speech such as verbs, nouns, adjectives?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, comparative-linguistics, parts-of-speech, second-lang-acquisition

I am developing a language learning tool in Python that generates dual-language books intended to be read as audio books.
The system should work by giving single word translations after every significant part of speech (verb, noun and adjective) that it is meant to translate.
So let's say you know English and you want to learn Spanish.
This tool takes a Spanish novel and copies it but after each verb, noun and adjective the translated English word is given.

I've learned that it isn't practical to do this using a traditional black-box machine learning model since those rely on context that is not available when being passed individual parts of speech.

So I am wondering what is an optimal method for translating these parts of speech with minimal ambiguity?

Comment: You can't translate words without context. It just can't be done. Context is essential.

Comment: I've guessed that but I think there are a good number of words that essentially only have one meaning.

Comment: Issue is that I have no obvious way to reconstruct from the output I'm given by my translator (argos translate currently). So one option is that I could make a function that reconstructs what the important parts of speech are. But I'm guessing there is a much better way to do it.

Comment: There might be a handful of words with no secondary senses, but the list of such words would be very small. But do their translations also have only one sense? The number of such word pairs would be almost non-existent. Consider that with all of the software developers and massive servers how bad Google Translate remains, and it *does* consider context.

Comment: I think the best option is that I could find a more advanced translation API that doesn't just act as a black box.

Comment: It's not about how advanced the translator is. As dannii put it, translating word by word without considering context just _can't be done_. Period. The best human translators in the world can't do a good translation word by word without context.

Comment: What about languages that use a different word order and different verb conjugation. (no past, present, future).  Often languages don't translate as word for word.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It is unclear to me what you intend.  Is it automatic translation, automatic vocabulary annotation, the same result as GoogleTranslate, except with annotation of parts of speech, or something else?

Comment: @Vegawatcher yes something like that but I'm seeing this now as an API question but still related to linguistics. I will find some more time to look deeper into these API's. Relevant APIs I'm currently using: argostranslate, nltk, spaCy.. Online translation services (Google, Baidu, Yandex, etc) I have found have too much latency on each request.

Comment: I'm still not completely clear on what you want, but you might want to reference what is done on these sites for Biblical Hebrew and Greek: https://biblehub.com/text/genesis/1-1.htm and https://biblehub.com/text/john/1-1.htm.  Since the languages are different, the parsing and annotations are different.